# Extracting coordinates from SVG path syntax

Tags: sas, cell, separator

*the title may be misleading

I have (column) cells values as follows:

```
d="M200,170L149,385"
d="M200,170L150,387" 
d="M200,170L275,384" 
d="M200,170L49,317" 
d="M200,170L92,347"
```

The values 200 & 170 in each cell represent the x and y origins respectively, while the second set of values (i.e. 149 and 385) represent the x and y values.
I want to separate the x-orgin, y-orgin, x and y values into four columns. (I'm relatively new to sas... I think these are cartesian coordinates)

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Perhaps a better title would be "Extracting coordinates from SVG path syntax". In the context of SVG each of your `d` values describes a line; `M` moves the pointer to the first location and `L` defines a line from the first location to the second. As the commands are capitalised the coordinates are absolute rather than relative. If you are interested you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d) or [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataMovetoCommands).

Comment: thanks SRSwift- Title has been changed as suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `scan` function. It is used to select the nth word of a string. First argument is the string you want parsed, second is the word (1st, 2nd, etc), and third lists your delimiters (characters that separate the words). That should be all you need.

```
data want;
  set have;
  origx = scan(d,1,'M,L');
  origy = scan(d,2,'M,L');
  x     = scan(d,3,'M,L');
  y     = scan(d,4,'M,L');
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a SAS dataset with a variable named d in it, or do you have a text file?  My first read was that you have a SAS dataset already, in which case you need to parse the variable.  You could use SCAN() function, or plenty of other methods, e.g.:

```
data have;
  input d $16.;
  cards;
M200,170L149,385
M200,170L150,387 
M200,170L275,384 
M200,170L49,317 
M200,170L92,347 
;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  x_origin=scan(d,1,"M,L");
  y_origin=scan(d,2,"M,L");
  x=scan(d,3,"M,L");
  y=scan(d,4,"M,L");
run;

proc print data=want;
run;
```